# Logistic Regression in statsmodels "LinAlgError: Singular matrix"

Tags: python, statsmodels

Not sure why but I'm getting a "numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix" error when fitting a logistic regression model.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = load_breast_cancer()
y = data.target
X = data.data

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y, random_state=2)

X_train = sm.add_constant(X_train)
X_test = sm.add_constant(X_test)
model = sm.Logit(y_train, X_train)
fit = model.fit() # error appears on this line

fit.summary2()
```

Comment: My guess is that the X_train set is singular because the split does not include all categories of a dummy variable. E.g. in a dataset with a gender dummy, if only females are in the training set, then we cannot estimate the gender effect.

Comment: There are no dummy variables in the X_train matrix, besides the column of 1's added with X_train = sm.add_constant(X_train)

Comment: The default optimization method `newton` breaks in this case. method='bfgs' works, but there is perfect prediction, so the parameters are not identified.

Comment: Thanks. What is unusual about this case such that the default optimisation breaks?

Comment: Predicted probabilities go to zero and one, the exp in logit transform will overflow. In general it is assumed that the predicted probabilities stay away from 0 and 1, but some parts of the code are made numerically robust to this case.

Comment: [refer this link where the solution is mentioned in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65217081/14605502)