# LinAlgError: Singular matrix from Statsmodels logistic regression

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I'm running a logistic regression on the Lalonde dataset to estimate propensity scores. I used the `logit` function from `statsmodels.statsmodels.formula.api` and wrapped the covariates with `C()` to make them categorical. Treating `age` and `educ` as continuous variables results in successful convergence but making them categorical raises the error

```
Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
         Current function value: 0.617306
         Iterations: 35
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-bae905b632a4> in <module>
----> 1 psmodel = fsms.logit('treatment ~ 1 + C(age) + C(educ) + C(black) + C(hisp) + C(married) + C(nodegr)', tdf).fit()
      2 tdf['ps'] = psmodel.predict()
      3 tdf.head()

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py in fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
   1832         bnryfit = super(Logit, self).fit(start_params=start_params,
   1833                 method=method, maxiter=maxiter, full_output=full_output,
-> 1834                 disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)
   1835 
   1836         discretefit = LogitResults(self, bnryfit)

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py in fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
    218         mlefit = super(DiscreteModel, self).fit(start_params=start_params,
    219                 method=method, maxiter=maxiter, full_output=full_output,
--> 220                 disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)
    221 
    222         return mlefit # up to subclasses to wrap results

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py in fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, fargs, callback, retall, skip_hessian, **kwargs)
    471             Hinv = cov_params_func(self, xopt, retvals)
    472         elif method == 'newton' and full_output:
--> 473             Hinv = np.linalg.inv(-retvals['Hessian']) / nobs
    474         elif not skip_hessian:
    475             H = -1 * self.hessian(xopt)

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in inv(a)
    549     signature = 'D->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'd->d'
    550     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 551     ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    552     return wrap(ainv.astype(result_t, copy=False))
    553 

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
     95 
     96 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 97     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
     98 
     99 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

To reproduce, load the [Lalonde dataset](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/matching/lalonde.html) (you can write to csv from R `data(lalonde)`) and run the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula import api as fsms

filename = 'lalonde.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
tdf = df.drop(['re74', 're75', 'u74', 'u75'], axis=1)
formula = 'treat ~ 1 + C(age) + C(educ) + C(black) + C(hisp) + C(married) + C(nodegr)'
psmodel = fsms.logit(formula, tdf).fit()
```

Not sure why this failed to converge / got to singular Hessian during training.

Interestingly, some examples I found online about causal inference and the lalonde dataset don't make the variables categorical, which makes no sense to me. One example is the [Microsoft DoWhy](https://github.com/Microsoft/dowhy/blob/master/dowhy/causal_estimators/propensity_score_weighting_estimator.py) which uses LogisticRegression from sklearn out-of-the-box. It does not encode the variables to be categorical it seems.

There are other similar examples involving running logistic regression on Lalonde dataset without making the variables categorical. These are numeric in the data but the values should not be treated as continuous. At least I feel they should be put into bins if not one category per value. But that's a different question which is more appropriate on CrossValidated. Could someone help me understand why I got this error and what's the right way to get rid of it?

Comment: You could try keeping age as continuous and not categorical variable, unless it is binned into large age groups. You can also try other optimizers, e.g. `method='nm'` or `method='bfgs'`. method newton can easily run into problems when we are far away from the optimum and the likelihood function is not well behaved locally. GLM with family binomial defines the same model with binary variables but uses by default IRLS which is likely also more robust to problems when away from the optimum.

Comment: @Josef Thanks for the comment. I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954406/logistic-regression-in-statsmodels-linalgerror-singular-matrix?rq=1). I'm a bit rusty on the inner working of the optimizers. Why does Newton method get singular matrix and BFGS doesn't? And what do you mean by likelihood function not behaving well locally? Isn't it convex everywhere?

Comment: `newton` is an optimizer in statsmodels that does not have any extra features to make it robust, it essentially just uses score and hessian. `bfgs` uses a hessian approximation and most scipy optimizers are more careful about finding a valid solution path. The negative loglikelihood function is "theoretically" globally convex, assuming well behaved, non-singular data. However, numerical noise and numerical problems (e.g. with `exp`) in the nonlinear computation can make it nonconvex or produce overflows in some examples.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error while running the following logistic model.

```
results = statsmodels.formula.api.logit('binary_outcome ~ x1 + x2 + const', data=df).fit()
print(results.summary())
```

After examining each variable, I found that one was, in fact, a constant.

```
df.const.value_counts()

1    100000
Name: Targeted, dtype: int64
```

Oops!

Upon removing it,

```
results = statsmodels.formula.api.logit('binary_outcome ~ x1 + x2', data=df).fit()
print(results.summary())
```

the logistic model ran as expected.

Comment: Confused, don't we want to have a constant in the model? I'm running into the same problem but in reverse. My model didn't have a constant and worked great, then I thought--hmm, but don't I need to add a constant? So I did, and then got this error. So now I'm confused. Do I just not need to add the constant?

Comment: We don't want a constant in the model!   Statistical models predict an outcome (variable) based on inputs (other variables); however, it is assumed that the input variables have some variation. If our variables were dependable (constants with no variation), we wouldn't need a fancy statistical model, for simple algebra would give the solution.    The statsmodel package creates a Design Matrix from the selected variables. When this matrix has a constant column, it's solution is singular (bad or non-existent). See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix) for a step in the right direction